# Best way encrypt password php (in 2017)

Tags: php, encryption, password-encryption

In my website I use `md5` to crypt password user in my database (and store session user)

```
$pswUser = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

But I have just been told that this way of encrypting has become obsolete

I did some research to find out how to do it but most of the posts dates from two or three years ago
So what is the best way to encrypt password in 2017 ?

Thank you

Isn't duplicate discussion ...
[Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) => 2009 ...

Comment: Most answers including the two highest voted on the linked question (duplicate) are actually still current.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The password hash function in combination with password verify

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php