# Best way to protect your password in 2019 with PHP

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

I'm just wondering what is the best way to encrypt your password with PHP in 2019.
I'm using this method, but many people tell me that is an unsafe way now:

```
$password_protect = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

I did some research but I find only for 2017. So, what is the best way for that?

Thank you

Comment: what did you find for 2017?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864379/best-way-encrypt-password-php-in-2017)

Comment: Now days you need to hash the password and use a random salt

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `password_hash()`.

Also check on `password_verify()`.

[PHP passwordhash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

And also check

[password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Example:

```
$password = "ABCDabcd";

echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>12));
```

The example should output something like this:

$2y$12$N6FSH8yRo0YMQ4oPJHN1vOkv7GfK3OhVp22H/AjGoVLY.5Dm7ECYS

To verify:
Say user input their password and you stored it in input variable;

```
$input = 'ABCDabcd';

$hashed_password = '$2y$12$N6FSH8yRo0YMQ4oPJHN1vOkv7GfK3OhVp22H/AjGoVLY.5Dm7ECYS';

if(password_verify($input,$hashed_password)){

echo 'password is valid';

}else{

echo 'Password is invalid';

}
```

This should return password is valid.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you.